# Python - Selenium Wire, how to delete interceptor param

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, seleniumwire

I'm looking for a little bit of help.

I'm using Selenium Wire to process the requests from a website and I need to change some settings in the requests.

I found the request_interceptor method which work perfectly. Problem is, I can only overwrite a param in the URL, I didn't find a way to delete one.

Let's say for instance, I go to the website : ***myawesomeweather.com/monday***
Let's say this url loads an api file called ***myawesomeweather.com/api/?d=monday&y=2021&m=03***
and get all the data for the mondays in march 2021.
To avoid doing multiples requests, I just want to modify the request for 2020, so I did this :

```
def ForceYear(request):
params = request.params
params['y'] = '2020'
request.params = params

driver.request_interceptor = ForceYear
driver.get(WeatherURL)
```

Which is perfect, I get the url api : ***myawesomeweather.com/api/?d=monday&y=2020&m=03***
But now I'd like to do all of the months for 2020, so i want to **remove** the **&m=03** and only have  ***myawesomeweather.com/api/?d=monday&y=2020***

How can I do it ? If I overwrite the &m= and put '', it doesn't work, the setting needs to be completely out of the link..

Thanks !

**-- Edit**

I should have searched more, basicaly the function just takes every parameters of the url and puts them into a dict, so just have to do this :

```
    if('m' in params):
          del params['m']
```

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the key from `params`

```
params.pop('m', None)
```

Comment: Thanks ! I actually found this way as well : del params['m']